# Avoid exporting of empty DataFrame to excel from python - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am working on an automation task in python...I have a large number of dataframes which i have to excel is there any way in which the exporting of empty dataframe can avoided when the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a DataFrame is empty by checking the shape of the DataFrame and comparing it's length.

```
number_of_row = df.shape[0]
if number_of_rows > 0:
    do_something(df)
else:
    something_else()
```